# Save nltk.ngram.NgramModel results

Tags: python, nltk, n-gram

I'm training an n-gram model on the Brown corpus using nltk.ngram.NgramModel. It's taking basically forever and using a LOT of system memory. I was wondering if there's a way to save the model so as not to have to train it again every time I run my code. I've seen references to pickle and BerkeleyDB, but I don't entirely understand how either of them work.

Thanks!

***ETA: I've been unable to successfully pickle the model, despite implementing the changes described [here](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=550) and trying all the various pickle protocol options. I've fooled around with simplejson (no luck) and YAML (takes forever, eats all my memory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pickle module allows you to serialize Python object structures so you can deserialize and use it later. Feel free to check the docs for further details http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

NLTK's NgramModel was serializable (w/ some efforts) in versions <= 2.0.1rc2 (or maybe it still is, but I was quite busy to investigate it further. Basically, you just need to use lower PROTOCOL_NUMBER when pickling it. You can check this (quite messy) code to see how I did it.

https://github.com/starenka/laholator/blob/master/laholator.py#L118

https://github.com/starenka/laholator/blob/master/laholator.py#L19

(The script powers couple sites which generate random text based on text samples. F.e this one http://kaluzator.starenka.net/

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The BerkeleyDB reference was probably one of my answers, or an article I wrote. Basically I wrote my own frequency table. Optimized for batch creation, it uses the NLTK implementation for in memory (say, 1000 input articles/files), and then it wrote it out to the main BerkeleyDB store. This reduced the number of (slow) BerkeleyDB writes. For example each sub-batch would only require one write for the word "the".

Answer (score 0):

Training a model is indeed something you should do once, and save for use multiple times. Pickle is the right tool, but who knows why it's not working for you? Google says there used to be some [problems with pickling ngrams](http://code.google.com/p/nltk/issues/detail?id=550), but they were fixed years ago. Keep trying, or make a **minimal** example and if it still doesn't work, post it here.